# UPS makes a clicking sound and my Network Connection stops

Tags: hardware-failure, ups

My uninterruptible power supply (UPS) makes a clicking sound then my network connection stops, what can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: The clicking sound is likely the UPS responding to the utility power winking out.  The fact that you lose your network connection implies that you have your router on the UPS, and the UPS isn't doing its job.  If the UPS is more than a few years old, it probably means its battery has died.  They're typically replaceable.  Or, it could mean that the battery is fine but you don't have the router plugged into power backup outlets on the UPS.  When the power winks off, the UPS keeps your computer going, but not the router.

Comment: My router isn't connected to the UPS. I have no way to connect as it's in a room far away from my UPS, unfortunately.

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that the problem only happens to this desktop PC (connected via an ethernet cable) and plugged into UPS. It does not happen to other devices, such WiFi ones.


Any ideas?